# CSS3 Animation won't start when mouse in window

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS§ animation, actually 3 elements animated. All animations are meant to start when the page is loaded.

They do - except when the mouse pointer is inside the window. Only the third element (#startheader) is animated delayed, just as it should.

This happens in Chrome and Safari Windows as far as I could test until now. Opera IE and Edge do not show this behaviour.

Here's the CSS:

```
#hg {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:#FFF;
  overflow:hidden;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  z-index:2;

  animation-name:scontan;
  animation-delay:5s;
  animation-duration:4s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;

  -webkit-animation-name:scontan;
  -webkit-animation-delay:5s;
  -webkit-animation-duration:4s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes scontan {
  from {
    height:100%;
  }
  to {
    height:92px;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes scontan {
  from {
    height:100%;
  }
  to {
    height:92px;
  }
}
#doedel {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:20%;
  transform:translateY(0);
  -webkit-transform:translateY(0);
  width:58%;

  animation-name:scontan2;
  animation-delay:5s;
  animation-duration:4s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-state:running;

  -webkit-animation-name:scontan2;
  -webkit-animation-delay:5s;
  -webkit-animation-duration:4s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-state:running;
}
@keyframes scontan2 {
  from {    
    transform:translateY(0);
  }
  to {    
    transform:translateY(-20%);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes scontan2 {
  from {    
    -webkit-transform:translateY(0);
  }
  to {    
    -webkit-transform:translateY(-20%);
  }
}
#startheader {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  height:92px;
  width:100%;
  background:rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
  opacity:0;
  z-index:3;

  animation-name:scontan3;
  animation-delay:9s;
  animation-duration:4s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;

  -webkit-animation-name:scontan3;
  -webkit-animation-delay:9s;
  -webkit-animation-duration:4s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes scontan3 {
  from {
    opacity:0;
  }
  to {
    opacity:1;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes scontan3 {
  from {
    opacity:0;
  }
  to {
    opacity:1;
  }
}
```

Ideas, anyone? Thanks!

Comment: full html plus css https://jsfiddle.net/eve0jr4h/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/eve0jr4h/2/

Comment: Please forget everything I wrote - the problem misteriously seems to have solved itself. I don't know why, but it doesn't happen anymore.